# Struct inside struct

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, typedef

I must create a Person and each Person should have a Fridge. Is this the best way of doing it? If so what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
typedef struct {
 int age;
 struct FRIDGE fridge;
} PERSON;

typedef struct {
 int number;
} FRIDGE;

FRIDGE fr;
fr.number=1;

PERSON me;
me.name=1;
me.fridge = fr;
```

This gives me the following error:

> error: field ‘fridge’ has incomplete type

Comment: You are using anonymous structure, so you should not use the `struct` keyword but use the `typedef`'ed name. Change `struct FRIDGE fridge` to `FRIDGE fridge`

Comment: @Manav: Editing the code in the question is the wrong way to answer it.  Edit the question code only to fix miserable formatting, like wrong indentation.

Comment: @BenVoigt: +1 Point Noted!!!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`struct FRIDGE` is something different than `FRIDGE`.

You need to either use type `FRIDGE` in your other structure.

```
typedef struct {
 int age;
 FRIDGE fridge;
} PERSON;
```

or define your fridge as `struct FRIDGE`

```
struct FRIDGE {
 int number;
};
```

Also, the structure may have to be defined before you use it (e.g. above the person).

Answer (score 4):

You have to use members of `FRIDGE`, after removing all warnings and errors. Declare `FRIDGE` before `PERSON`

`me.fridge.number = 1`

**EDITED**: I found the bug. You are using anonymous structure, so you should not use the `struct` keyword but use the `typedef`ed name.

Change `struct FRIDGE fridge`
to `FRIDGE fridge`

Comment: That's not the problem, modern dialect of C support direct assignment of structures. See the error message.

Comment: If you do forward declaration of `FRIDGE`, the error is gone. It is always *advisable* to assign values to structure members and not to entire structure unless doing something like `memset`. This avoids errors in future when more struct members are added to it's declaration.

Comment: Well, that's what the original code is doing. You have `fr` initialized using the member, and then you're just putting the structure in the other structure. There won't be any errors if you add more members. (Additionally, sometimes I want my code to fail when underlying structures are extended. It may be a useful reminder to add missing initialization.)

Comment: ...not to mention that your second line assigns a fridge structure to `int`.

Comment: @che: when you declare `struct A { struct B xyz;};` the preceding line should be `struct B;` or a full definition of `struct B` otherwise how would the compiler calculate the size of `struct B` and know how much memory to allocate for your final `struct A`??

Comment: Well, let's try it then, declaring FRIDGE before PERSON, and using its members: https://gist.github.com/4380192

Comment: @che: I found the `bug` and updated my answer. Check it out, and would you mind removing the `down-vote` from my answer !!

Answer (score 2):

Using typedefs with your structs will get you into this kind of tangle. The struct keyword in front of a struct tag identifier is how structs are supposed to be used, this is also more explicit and easier to read.

There is a long and good blog post with all the details here
https://www.microforum.cc/blogs/entry/21-how-to-struct-lessons-on-structures-in-c/

But in short what you really want to do is leave out the typedef's like this

```
struct FRIDGE;  // This is a forward declaration, now an incomplete type

struct PERSON{
 int age;
 struct FRIDGE fridge;
};

struct FRIDGE{
 int number;
};

struct FRIDGE fr;
fr.number=1;

struct PERSON me;
me.name=1;
me.fridge = fr;
```

Linus Torvalds also went on about this once, very solid reasoning why using typedefs on all your structs is confusing and bad.

https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/typedefs.html

Answer (score 1):

Either do the forward declaration of `struct FRIDGE;`

Or,

give the definition of `FRIDGE` before using it in struct `PERSON`

Comment: The code does contain a forward declaration.  But a forward declaration is not sufficient here, to embed an instance (rather than a pointer), the full definition is needed.