# Limitations in "struct inside struct"

Tags: c, struct

There are 2 `struct` definitions `A` and `A`.  I know that there is OK to `struct A` contain  a **POINTER** to `struct A` but I don't understand why `struct A` **cannot** contains `struct A` (not a pointer)

Comment: I would have another go at this question - perhaps with a dictionary to hand

Comment: Don't quite understand your question, dude

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Struct inside struct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040612/struct-inside-struct)

Comment: So you want [Turtles all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down)?

Comment: Not duplicate. @Koni asks how to create recursive struct without using pointers.

Comment: @Arnial: It is a dup! That is simply nonsense. Just apply occam's razor!

Comment: In question [Struct inside struct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040612/struct-inside-struct). Sok tryes to put struct *FRIDGE into PERSON*, not *PERSON into PERSON* or *FRIDGE into FRIDGE*. Koni tryes to put *A into A*.

Comment: This could be a _good_ question if OP detailed more the line of thinking used to suppose this is possible.  Perhaps the view is that all data is referenced?  IDK, but would like to understand OP's point-of-view even if it leads to a recursive rabbit hole.

Answer (score 5):

Because when you put structs inside each other, you're putting *another copy* of that struct into the struct at that point. For example:

```
struct A {
    int q;
    int w;
};
struct B {
    int x;
    struct A y;
    int z;
};
```

This will be laid out in memory like this:

```
int /*B.*/x;
int /*A.*/q;
int /*A.*/w;
int /*B.*/z;
```

But if you try to put a struct inside itself:

```
struct A {
    int x;
    struct A y;
};
```

you have an A, which contains an int and another A, which contains an int and another A, and now you have an infinite number of ints.

Answer (score 3):

Because in that case, it will take infinite storage as it will have to recursively store the data member of its own type. So, it is not possible. Whereas, Size of a pointer is fixed and hence causes no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because the structure definition is not finished until the closing curly-brace `}`. To declare a structure member the compiler need the full definition, as it uses that information to calculate things like space and padding and alignment etc. For a pointer to something the size of the pointer is the size of the pointer, and all the compiler needs os the name of the type, not its full definition.

Lets take a simple structure for example:

```
struct A   // Here the compiler knows that there is a structure named A
           // The compiler does not know its contents, nor its size
{
    // Some members...

    struct A *pointer_to_a;  // All the compiler needs to know is the symbol A
                             // The size and alignment is that of a pointer
                             // and those are known by the compiler

    // Some more members...

    // struct A instance_of_A;  // This is not possible! At this point the
                                // compiler doesn't have the full definition
                                // of the structure, and can therefore not
                                // know how much space it need to allocate
                                // for the member

    // Some even more members...
}
// Now the compiler knows the full contents of the structure, its size
// and alignment requirements
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose it could contain an object of its own type:

```
struct A_
{
   A_ a;
   int b;
} A;
```

What's `sizeof(A)` ? Answer: `sizeof(A)+sizeof(int)`: impossible.