# How does a structure as another structures member work logically?

Tags: c

For example the code below. I understand what the members are, but to have a struct as a member is confusing to me and I cant find anywhere how this works or what that line of code does. Please don't crucify me for trying to understand. Ive searched and searched and I cant find an answer.

```
struct point
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
struct rectangle
{
    struct point upper_left;     //how does this line of code operate 
    struct point lower_right;    //and this line of code
};
```

Comment: `struct rectangle r; r.upper_left.x = 5;`

Comment: Related read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040612/struct-inside-struct

Comment: The logic is to avoid repetition. If you didn't have the `point` struct, you have to have 4 int members e.g. `upleftX`, `upleftY`, `bottRightX`, `bottRightY`. Having this repetition factored out will keep your code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). The child struct literally just exists within its parent. It has no size penalty beside its own size and padding to maintain word alignment, if the structs size required it (here I believe it doesn't).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Struct inside struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040612/struct-inside-struct)

Comment: No, not a duplicate question, the other answers I didn't explain the logic.

Comment: In that case, you've to mention the other (duplicate) questions and that why the answers are not helpful and different from your question.

Comment: I see, thanks for the feedback. Im new to stackoverflow, so next time I will follow your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structure rectangle contains two variables (structure variables) which represent two points, the upper left and the lower right, that will form the rectangle. As the point is composed of two coordinates that is `x` and `y`, so you created a structure variable `point`, having two values, which is `x`and `y` coordinate.

Now let's put valurs.

`struct rectangle rect1 = {{3,4}, {10,11}};`

So here, it is interpreted like this.

`rect1.upper_left = {3,4}`

which is further as

```
 upper_left.x = 3;
 upper_left.y = 4;
```

So actually it is assigned as

```
rect1.upper_left.x = 3;
rect1.upper_left.y = 4;
```

Similarly in case of `lower_right` member.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question!!

Comment: Your most welcome, that's why I'm here early in the morning, to answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pictorial representation of `struct rectangle rect1 = {{3,4}, {10,11}};`

In reality the stuff inside the blue rectangles is using up memory, and the padding areas outside of it are not using up memory, but I drew it this way in my diagram to leave room for the name labels.

[image]